# Send value to php file

Tags: php

I'm try to send a value to a PHP file, but when I check, this value became `null`.

I send the value by: user_login.php?p_action=New_User

The code of user_login.php is:

```
require("include/session_inc.php");
require("include/user_handling_inc.php");
require("include/db_inc.php");

start_Session(false, false);

switch ($p_action) {
case 'Login': {
 $l_flag = verify_User($p_in_username, $p_in_password);
 if ($l_flag == "Not_Found") {
     $l_flag = "New_User";
 }
 break; 
}
case 'Save_Profile': {
$l_flag = "Save_Profile";
    break;
}
case 'New_User':
$l_flag = "New_User";
    break;
case 'Create_New_User':
$l_flag = "Create_New_User";
}

switch ($l_flag) {
    case 'New_User': {
    include "include/user_new_inc.php";
    break;
  }
case 'Save_Profile': {
    load_User_Data(" username = '$p_in_username' ", false);
    include "include/user_profile_save_inc.php";
    break;
  }
case 'Wrong_Password': 
    echo "Wrong Pass";
    break;
case 'OK': 
    load_User_Data(" username = '$p_in_username' ", true);
    store_User_Cookie($g_userdata->user_id);
    include "include/user_profile_inc.php";
    break;
case 'Create_New_User':
$l_user_id = create_New_User ($p_in_username, $p_in_email, 'Y');
    if ($l_user_id != -1) {
        store_User_Cookie($l_user_id);
        echo "Success !! <br><br> \n";
        echo "<a href\"/index.php\"> Back to Main </a>";
     }
break;
}
```

Comment: read about `$_GET`. What you are trying to do is PHP3 retro-code using global variables

Comment: Reading this code, I suspect that the function 'load_User_Data()' performs some database query, (SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$p_in_username'). Without properly escaping $p_in_username, this will be very dangerous code, because SQL Injection is likely. I'd advise you to check that code and do some research on SQL Injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code isn't correct please read more about using Switch [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

second to access to any variable came from url you can use Global variable  $_GET or $_REQUEST

and you can read more about them from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

and this is your code after fixing it please try to run it

```
  <?php
require("include/session_inc.php");
require("include/user_handling_inc.php");
require("include/db_inc.php");

start_Session(false, false);
$p_action=$_GET["p_action"];

switch ($p_action) {
case 'Login':
 $l_flag = verify_User($p_in_username, $p_in_password);
 if ($l_flag == "Not_Found") {
     $l_flag = "New_User";
}
 break; 

case 'Save_Profile': 
$l_flag = "Save_Profile";
    break;

case 'New_User':
$l_flag = "New_User";
    break;
case 'Create_New_User':
$l_flag = "Create_New_User";
 break;
}

switch ($l_flag) {
    case 'New_User': 
    include "include/user_new_inc.php";
    break;

case 'Save_Profile': 
    load_User_Data(" username = '$p_in_username' ", false);
    include "include/user_profile_save_inc.php";
    break;

case 'Wrong_Password': 
    echo "Wrong Pass";
    break;
case 'OK': 
    load_User_Data(" username = '$p_in_username' ", true);
    store_User_Cookie($g_userdata->user_id);
    include "include/user_profile_inc.php";
    break;
case 'Create_New_User':
$l_user_id = create_New_User ($p_in_username, $p_in_email, 'Y');
    if ($l_user_id != -1) {
        store_User_Cookie($l_user_id);
        echo "Success !! <br><br> \n";
        echo "<a href\"/index.php\"> Back to Main </a>";
     }
break;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the code like this friend

```
switch ($_GET["p_action"]) {
case 'Login': {
 $l_flag = verify_User($p_in_username, $p_in_password);
 if ($l_flag == "Not_Found") {
     $l_flag = "New_User";
 }
```

that well give you the value of the get!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to get your parameter.

Sometimes [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) is preferable since it access both get & post data.

2nd thing never trust the user input so you must use [addslashes();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function to prevent attacks on the system.

So Code would be like this :

```
$var = addslashes($_GET['p_action']);

switch($p) {
   case 'Login':
    $l_flag = verify_User($p_in_username, $p_in_password);
    if ($l_flag == "Not_Found") {
        $l_flag = "New_User";
    }
    break;

   "OTHER CASES HERE"
}
```

> **Notice that : Don't add { } for CASE. Read syntax for switch
>   [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)**